# There is an error on line 12 of custom code BC30205 End of statement expected using rdl VBA

Tags: vba, rdlc, vba7, vba6

I am working on an application I am facing an issue below is the error and the code

> [rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 12 of custom code: [BC30205] End of statement expected using rdl VBA

```
 <Code>

Function SetLocationValue(locationId as Integer, allLoc as Integer) As String
      Dim ret as String = ""
      if allLoc = 1 Then
             ret =  "&lt;root Selected="all"/&gt;"
      else
            ret =  "&lt;root Selected="list"&gt;&lt;id&gt; CStr(locationId)  &lt;/id&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"
      End If
            return ret
End Function

<!---SET DEPARTMENT-->
      
Function SetDepartmentValue(deptId As Integer, allDept As Integer) As String
      Dim ret as String = ""
      if allDept = 1 Then
            ret =  "&lt;root Selected="all"/&gt;"
      else
            ret =  "&lt;root Selected="list"&gt;&lt;id&gt; CStr(deptId)  &lt;/id&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"
      End if
            return ret
End Function
      
      <!---END-->


</Code>
```

Comment: That code is not for VBA. For example, this `Dim ret as String = ""` is not valid VBA. That is VB.NET

Comment: VBA doesn't use `return`: if you want to assign the return value for a function you use `[name of function] = [return value]`   Eg: `SetDepartmentValue = ret`

Comment: Also `Dim ret as String = ""`  - you can't combine declaration with assignment in VBA

Comment: I can edit my question may that can help

Comment: I have added my code to the Code tag in the .rdl report.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rdl VBA. If it follows similar syntax as Office VBA, double quotation marker should be used in `ret =  "&lt;root Selected=""all""/&gt;"`

Comment: @taller my solution is built now. Thank you so much for your comment.